# Firefox not rendering jQuery templates

Tags: javascript, jquery, templates, firefox, jquery-templates

I'm using jQuery templates for a website I developed and they work perfectly fine on Chrome, Safari, and even IE9, but the templates just won't render on Firefox.  I'm loading them externally, and the $.get is processed (I've checked Firebug, the get goes through and pulls the right file), but then I'm greeted with a blank page and inspecting the html reveals the body element contains only the footer (included in the html), but with display : none, which is how it should be, so the javascript ran to completion (since the footer is hidden inside the loadtemplate functions).  It seems that Firefox is simply skipping the $.tmpl() call.  Here's the function :

```
var loadTemplate = function(templateName){
     $.get(templateName, function(template){
        $.tmpl(template).appendTo("body");
    });
};
var loadHomePage = function(){
    history = [];
    clearPage();
    loadTemplate("./templates/home.tmpl");
    current_page = "./templates/home.tmpl";
}
var clearPage = function(){
  $(".page-content").remove();
  $(".page-header").remove();
  $("#popup-container").remove();
  $(".page-footer").hide();
};
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I can follow up with more code if required as well.

EDIT: even works on Opera, I don't need to support it so the styles don't work (using LESS which Opera doesn't support and a css file strictly for IE), but it still loads the templates without a problem.

Comment: Have you done any debugging on the $.get request? is it throwing an error? The error may not show up in firebug, you should use the `.fail()` callback on it.

Comment: $.get returns either code 200 or code 304, and Firebug actually allows you to see the file that was "got", which is exactly correct

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't tell you if jQuery parsed the response properly.

Comment: Added in both a .error() callback and a .done .fail() and it did not enter either of them.
EDIT: not at the same time of course

Comment: Next thing to test would be to confirm the value you are passing into $.tmpl() to ensure it is the same in firefox as the other browsers.

Comment: Okay now I think we might be on to something, Safari considers template as a string, whereas Firefox considers its a DOM document, unless Safari's console is just calling a toString on the document automatically.  Still confusing though as .tmpl() should work perfectly well on a DOM element as well.

Comment: This should give you an accurate type for debugging: `console.log($.type(template));`

Comment: Yeah, safari considers it a string and firefox an object.

Comment: Add `,"text"` after your success callback in `$.get()` to see if it properly forces it to return text in firefox.

Comment: That printed just the header of the template, which is locked up inside a <div> tag.  ie:
<div> My Header </div>
and then forcing datatype as either text or html makes the "body" of the page: My Header, no tags

Comment: @KevinB That last attempt actually did work, adding "text" parameter to the $.get(), I had accidentally wrapped up template in a jquery object somewhere in the debugging process and was getting junk as a result.  If you want you can post it up as an answer now and I'll accept it right away.  Thanks again for all the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Requesting a template may get processed as HTML by some browsers, which in-turn can result in a mangled template. Try setting the datatype to "text" so that all browsers properly return un-modified text.

```
$.get(templateName, function(template){
    $.tmpl(template).appendTo("body");
}, "text");
```